# how to gradually increase camera speed moving upwards in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a game in which the camera moves in the y-axis (upwards) with gradually increasing speed.

```
void Update () {
        float translation = 0.5f;
        transform.Translate (0, translation, 0);
```

I used this code, but I want to increase the rate of speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to create a timer and increment the speed every time X amount of seconds has passed:

```
float translation = 0.5f;
float timer = 0f;

void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer > 1f) //after 1 second has passed...
    {
        timer = 0; // reset timer
        translation += 0.5f; //increase speed by 0.5
    }

    transform.Translate (0, translation, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions like `Vector3.Lerp()`, `Vector3.MoveTowards` and `Mathf.Lerp()`, `Mathf.MoveTowards()` will help you do just that.

You can also multiply your translation by Time.deltaTime and control the speed by controlling the translation value.

Answer (score 1):

```
public float BaseTranslationSpeed = 0.5f ;
public float TranslationSpeedIncreaseRate = 1 ;
private float translationSpeed ;

void Start()
{
    translationSpeed = BaseTranslationSpeed ;
}

void Update ()
{
    translationSpeed += TranslationSpeedIncreaseRate ;
    // Multiplying by Time.deltaTime is advised in order to be frame independant
    transform.Translate (0, translationSpeed * Time.deltaTime , 0);
}
```

---

You can even use an Animation curve to control the speed :

```
public AnimationCurve SpeedOverTime ; // Change the curve in the inspector
private float startTime ;

void Start()
{
    startTime = Time.time ;
}

void Update ()
{
    // Multiplying by Time.deltaTime is advised in order to be frame independant
    transform.Translate (0, SpeedOverTime.Evaluate( Time.time - startTime ) * Time.deltaTime , 0);
}
```